# How to select values in an array until a threshold value?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I will explain my problem. I have a 1x1701 sampled array  "resampled_WF",  once I found the max value of this array ("peak_WF"), I set a threshold 0.7*peak_WF, and I would like to select the farthest value in the array that gets nearer to this threshold.
Example:
[power_vs_time_threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lfgq.jpg)

As you can see, I was able to select ony the first value that resembles... but I would like to get the last one (around t=2 sec).
I tried to flip the array with "flip" function:

```
WF_threshold_input = 0.7*peak_WF;
flip_resampled_WF = flip(resampled_WF);
diff_peak_threshold = peak_WF - WF_threshold_input; %power loss at 70% power reduction
diff_peak_WF = peak_WF - flip_resampled_WF;
min_diff_threshold = min(abs(diff_peak_WF-diff_peak_threshold));
```

Doing that, MATLAB computes minimum difference on the whole array, I would like to stop at the first value, not considering further values.
I tried to select values with  values <= WF_threshold_input, but again it selects over the whole dataset.

How can I select the value properly?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using operations on the matrix will call the operation on every element in the matrix. What you want to do is use a loop so that you can control exactly what elements are examined and then break out of the loop.

```
index = length(resampled_WF);

your_threshold = ...

while resampled_WF(index) < your_threshold
   index = index - 1;
end
```

The while loop will continue iteration until it reaches a value that is outside of your defined threshold.

After execution, the value of `index` will be the index of the furthest value in the array which is outside of your threshold. You can access the furthest value outside the threshold by looking at `resampled_wf(index)` after execution of the code.

We don't have to worry about the values of index leaving the bounds of the array, ie <1, since the condition `resampled_wf < your_threshold` is guaranteed to be met by the maximal value that you originally generated the threshold with.

Comment: NIce idea to use the while loop! I got what I needed, thanks!